# how to sort list of tuples within a list?

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, tuples

I want to sort lists of tuples of mathematical operators (stored as strings) and their index, in order of precedence (*,/,+,-), while retaining their original index. There are thousands of lists of tuples within my list.

E.g.

```
my_lists = [[(0,'*'),(1,'+'),(2,'-')],[(0,'-'),(1,'*'),(2,'*')],[(0,'+'),(1,'/'),(2,'-')]]
```

should become:

```
new_list = [[(0,'*'),(1,'+'),(2,'-')],[(1,'*'),(2,'*'),(0,'-')],[(1,'/'),(0,'+'),(2,'-')]]
```

I've tried using the 'sorted' built in function and storing the precedence in a dictionary.

```
priority = {'*': 0, '/': 1, '+': 2, '-': 3}

new_list = [sorted(item, key = priority.get) for item in my_lists]
```

This produces the same original list.

How do I access just the operator part of the tuple whilst sorting the list of tuples?

Comment: What did you try? Show your approach, and others may help you to get it done, but StackOverflow is not a coding service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting using the whole tuple as key, such as `(0, '*')`. You have to use the second part of it only (i.e. `x[1]`):

```
[sorted(item, key = lambda x: priority.get(x[1])) for item in my_lists]
```

returns

```
[[(0, '*'), (1, '+'), (2, '-')],
 [(1, '*'), (2, '*'), (0, '-')],
 [(1, '/'), (0, '+'), (2, '-')]]
```

Your code didn't throw an error, because `priority.get((0, '*'))` is legal and returns `None`, which is perfectly sortable in Python 2.7 and keeps the list in its original order.